# scores and loadings in princomp (PCA)

Tags: r, pca, feature-selection, data-mining

I applied PCA on the dataset, but I am confused
what should I use to build the model, the components in scores or in the loadings?

---

@ usεr11852

```
> str(pc)
    List of 7
     $ sdev    : Named num [1:32] 3.12 2.87 1.83 1.5 1.24 ...
      ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4" ...
     $ loadings: loadings [1:32, 1:32] -0.2081 -0.0148 -0.2246 -0.2113 -0.1443 ...
      ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "radius_mean" "texture_mean" "perimeter_mean" "area_mean" ...
      .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4" ...
     $ center  : Named num [1:32] 17.402 22.301 114.781 969.092 0.103 ...
      ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "radius_mean" "texture_mean" "perimeter_mean" "area_mean" ...
     $ scale   : Named num [1:32] 3.1635 4.3241 21.3754 352.2486 0.0126 ...
      ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "radius_mean" "texture_mean" "perimeter_mean" "area_mean" ...
     $ n.obs   : int 194
     $ scores  : num [1:194, 1:32] 1.75 -6.38 -1.25 -3.58 -1.27 ...
      ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      .. ..$ : chr [1:194] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
      .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4" ...
     $ call    : language princomp(x = wpdc[, 2:33], cor = TRUE, scores = TRUE)
     - attr(*, "class")= chr "princomp"
```

Comment: Check how the structure (`str`) of your R `princomp` function looks like. The dimensions of the relevant matrices give out the answer.

Comment: You build your model with the scores.